# Work with C# Project and Solution programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj, sln-file

I am looking for approach add existing C# Project (.csproj) into solution (.sln) programmatically on C#. Will be good if posible escape use “illegal” way like parsing and edit xml document.

At the end of work, result should be like adding existing C# Project via Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: It is legal to edit a file on your local computer.

Comment: I found the duplicate in under a minute, less time than it took to write this...

Comment: As a starting point check out the [Microsoft .Net APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/index?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) - there are lots of APIs for accessing Visual Studio & several for projects in particular languages.

Answer (score 2):

This highly depends on the VS version you target.

This is like the latest link on [How to: Programmatically Create Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228767.aspx).
It contains a big well-commented code sample that you can copy-paste and modify to meet your needs.

Also see these links:

- [Controlling the Solution and Its Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t51cz75w.aspx)
- [Manipulating Visual Basic and Visual C# Projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228761.aspx)